# Solutions of a PDE

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Find all the non-negative solutions of:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x} = -u^2$

with boundary data:

$u(0,t) = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t\in(0,\tau)$

$u(a,t) = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t\in(0,\tau)$

$u(x,0) = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in(0,a)$

The question was asked in the context of uniqueness, so it seems likely that this will have more than one solution.

Comment: If you expect it to only have one solution, then that solution would be $u=0$

Comment: I'm saying that it's likely to have more than 1 solution

Comment: Hah, totally misread that

Comment: Assume $u_{1}, u_{2}$ are solutions to the PDE and look at the sum $v := u_{1} + u_{2}$. What does the new PDE become? What does the data become?